# How to get Device Id in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How to get the unique Device in Windows Store App (Metro App)?

Can we use:

**Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);**

```
 Windows.System.Profile.HardwareToken hToke = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
IBuffer hardwareId = hToke.Id;
IBuffer signature = hToke.Signature;
IBuffer certificate = hToke.Certificate;
DataReader reader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);
byte[] ar = new Byte[hardwareId.Length];
reader.ReadBytes(ar);
string i = ar.ToString();
string id = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ar, 0, ar.Length);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID" + Convert.ToBase64String(ar));
```

**Network adapter Id of first Network adapter found**

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Windows.Networking.Connectivity.ConnectionProfile> profiles =
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkAdapter na = profiles.First<Windows.Networking.Connectivity.ConnectionProfile>().NetworkAdapter;
string nid =  na.NetworkAdapterId.ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a [suggested](http://www.wadewegner.com/2012/09/getting-the-application-id-and-hardware-id-in-windows-store-applications/) way:

```
   private string GetHardwareId()
    {
        var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
        var hardwareId = token.Id;
        var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
    }
```

Or, you have problems with this method?

Comment: I am able to get the Id with  this. But issue is different applications on same device gives different ID. I need a ID which should be unique for all Apps on that device

Comment: So what about using the NetworkAdapterId of of the first adapter in connection profile. I think the first adapter is always Ethernet. So What about using the NetworkAdapterId as unique device Id?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431 there are some ideas

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other way I found:

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = 
  new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();

var myDeviceID = deviceInfo.Id;
```