# unique identifier for metro application

Tags: microsoft-metro

I need unique identifier for Windows Store application , I have read 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893637/how-to-get-device-id-in-windows-8-metro-app) ,but I need to know if user uninstall my application and install it again from Windows Store what would happen,and If I update my application and user reinstall it ?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Guidance on using the App Specific Hardware ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj553431#Using_the_API):

> The [HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken) method
>   provides a means for Windows Store apps to generate an ASHWID of the
>   device they are running on. Two apps calling this API return different
>   ASHWIDs on the same device. For a given app/package, the ASHWID is not
>   affected by:
>
> - OS re-installs
> - A push button reset
> - OS SKU upgrade
> - **Version updates for an app**
> - Changing users on the same device

If you change the package name (and I presume the publisher) you will get a different value.

Note that the value also reflects a number of properties (some potentially transient) of the device, so two subsequent executions of the same app could return different values.